# Add widgets and retrieve values programmatically - customtkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, slider, customtkinter

New to python and working on a user interface that has several `sliders` to control some parameters. Each `slider` has its own `label` displaying the name and the current value. The value shown on the `label` should be updated and also be retrieved by other functions. While I can do this explicitly, it is not scalable as the number of `sliders` increases.

Desired Output:

[image]

Single slider with label:

```
import customtkinter as ctk

# define colour palette
app_color = '#121212'
frame_color = '#1e1e1e'
text_color = '#e3e3e3'

def sliderFunc1(value):
    val = slider1.get()
    lab1.configure(text=lab1_text + str(val) + '%')

# Slider class 

class myslider(ctk.CTkSlider):
    def __init__(self, master, width=150, height=10, command=sliderFunc1, value=80):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.configure(width=width, height=height, orientation='horizontal', 
                       from_=0, to=100, number_of_steps=20, corner_radius=5, border_color='#423e47', 
                       fg_color='#423e47', button_color='white', button_corner_radius=8, 
                       progress_color='transparent', command=command)
        self.set(value)

# Declare App
app = ctk.CTk(fg_color='grey')
app.title('Dummy App')
app._set_appearance_mode('dark')
app.geometry('740x620')

frame1 = ctk.CTkFrame(master=app, fg_color='#1e1e1e', width=400)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=50, pady=50)
frame1.grid_propagate(0)

lab1_text = 'Parameter 1: '
lab1 = ctk.CTkLabel(master=frame1, text=lab1_text, fg_color='transparent', 
                    font=('Segoe UI', 10), text_color='#e3e3e3', anchor='w')
lab1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=(10,0))

slider1 = myslider(master=frame1, command=sliderFunc1)
slider1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=50)

app.mainloop()
```

I can place several sliders in a grid format using two loops but have no idea how to pass a specific function for each slider or retrieve values (for updating label, use elsewhere).

Loop:

```
c = 1
for i in range(0,2):
    for j in range (0,2):
        lab_text = 'Parameter {}: '.format(c)
        c += 1
        lab = ctk.CTkLabel(master=frame1, text=lab_text, fg_color='transparent', 
                           font=('Segoe UI', 10), text_color='#e3e3e3', anchor='w')
        lab.grid(row=2*i, column=j, sticky='w', padx=10, pady=(10,0))
        sl = myslider(master=frame1, width=170)
        sl.grid(row=2*i+1, column=j, padx=(10,0))
```

Loop Output:

[image]

In other languages I've used a `list` structure effectively but unsure how to do it in python.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the related label, you need to pass the label reference and `lab_text` to the function.

Below is the modified code:

```py
import customtkinter as ctk

# define colour palette
app_color = '#121212'
frame_color = '#1e1e1e'
text_color = '#e3e3e3'

# function to update label when the slider value is changed
def sliderFunc(label, prompt, value):
    label.configure(text=f"{prompt}: {value}%")

# Slider class
class myslider(ctk.CTkSlider):
    def __init__(self, master, width=150, height=10, command=None, value=80):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.configure(width=width, height=height, orientation='horizontal',
                       from_=0, to=100, number_of_steps=20, corner_radius=5, border_color='#423e47',
                       fg_color='#423e47', button_color='white', button_corner_radius=8,
                       progress_color='transparent', command=command)
        self.set(value)
        if command: command(value)  # show initial value

# Declare App
app = ctk.CTk(fg_color='grey')
app.title('Dummy App')
app._set_appearance_mode('dark')
app.geometry('740x620')

frame1 = ctk.CTkFrame(master=app, fg_color='#1e1e1e', width=400)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=50, pady=50)
frame1.grid_propagate(0)

c = 1
for i in range(0,2):
    for j in range (0,2):
        lab_text = 'Parameter {}'.format(c)
        c += 1
        lab = ctk.CTkLabel(master=frame1, text=lab_text, fg_color='transparent',
                           font=('Segoe UI', 10), text_color='#e3e3e3', anchor='w')
        lab.grid(row=2*i, column=j, sticky='w', padx=10, pady=(10,0))
        sl = myslider(master=frame1, width=170,
                      command=lambda val, lab=lab, prompt=lab_text: sliderFunc(lab, prompt, val))
        sl.grid(row=2*i+1, column=j, padx=(10,0))

app.mainloop()
```